# Python. Алгоритм перебора двух списков, ищу идею

Tags: python, алгоритм, list, сравнение

При прогоне дампа формируются N CSV файлов. Сохраняем их в качестве эталонных. При повторном прогоне снова формируется N CSV файлов. Передо мной стоит задача определить в последнем прогоне сформировались точно те же данные в файлах что и в эталонном ? Имена файлов формируются случайным образом, с включением даты-времени, для использования в сравнении не годятся. Усугубляет дело то что в каждом из списков имеются по несколько одинаковых по размеру файлов. Каким образом определить пару (а потом уже я сравню содержимое) ? В другом месте реализовывал так - сравнивал один файл 1 списка по очереди со всеми файлами 2 списка. Эмпирически вычислил порог разницы (10 отличий - дата, время, имя файла), разница ниже порога принималось за "пару", ну а выше - за "чужой" файл. Может есть более интересное и правильное решение ? Подкиньте идею, пож.

Comment: а сравнивать контрольные суммы файлов не вариант?

Comment: Пусть у вас M файлов одинакового размера. Сделать M*M сравнений едва ли настолько дорого, чтобы искать трюки. Поскольку у вас файлы структурированы, то достаточно сравнивать только несколько первых строк, чтобы отсеять неэквивалентные. Ну или как предложил @strawdog, вместо содержимого сравнить контрольные суммы или хэши, но в случае больших (десятки мегабайт) файлов сравнение первых строк гораздо дешевле, чем вычисление контрольной суммы.

Comment: в состав файла входят дата-время, т.е. просто хэшами целого файла не отделаться. Нужно открывать, исключать переменные среды, вычислять хэш.  Если в паре будут отличия то вывести их. А для этого нужно точно определиться с парой.

Comment: Рукописный объект файл. Сделайте ему вычисление хеша и сравнение на равенство. Поместите ваши файлы в хеш-таблицу. Вообще ничем не отличается от поиска дублей для любых объектов.

Comment: Какой суммарный объём файлов?

Comment: В чем суть поиска дублей ?Мне же нужно будет показать разницу между файлами. Всего разное кол-во,  несколько сотен может быть, размеры файлов не более 3 кБ,

Comment: 600KB всего. Загрузите все файлы в память и сопоставляйте тексты как длинные строки.

Comment: В принципе, так и делаю. Разбираю XML, превращаю нужные параметры в словарь и потом сравниваю словари.